# Is there a way to print checksum256 variable?

Tags: hash

Is there a way to print checksum256 variable?

Like:

```
checksum256 hash;
print(hash);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `printhex( &hash, sizeof(hash) )`.

Basically, `checksum256` is a struct containing an array of 32 `uint8` numbers.